# How to use MasterMap address layer with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a copy of QGIS.  I have a MasterMap address layer for my area.  How do I get the map onto my computer and open it please?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment - Loading the gml directly into QGIS will give you very limited amounts of information for Mastermap.

This is the basic structure related the ROAD Feature TOIDS to roadname and address

[image]

ESRI (UK) have the [Productivity Suite](http://www.esriuk.com/software/arcgis/productivitysuite) that does sort out the relationships

Snowflake [GoLoader](http://www.snowflakesoftware.com/markets/ordnancesurvey/) is  another

The user needs to maintain the following with Mastermap

```
Change only Update (CoU) – Update only the changes supplied by OS and use its valuable change intelligence to keep your data up-to-date

Geographic and Non-geographic chunking options – Load non-geographic chunking to remove the need for duplicate removal

Compressed and uncompressed data – Don’t waste valuable disk space and processing time. Load compressed data directly
Style guide – Use our style guide plugin to style OS MasterMap and OS VectorMap according to the OS Style Guide. Not just that be also provide default ArcGIS layers file and MapInfo tab files

Feature Validation Data Set (FVDS) – When you’ve loaded everything ensure your data holding is aligned with OS view of the world

Duplicate removal – If you need to load geographically chunked data then remove duplicates directly from within GO Loader

Historical archiving – Linked to CoU, create views that go back in time and answer questions such as ‘what did my OS Mastermap look like when I captured my data 3 years ago?’

ITN Road Routing Information (RRI) – Visualise the routing information in ITN RRI to display precise turn restrictions

GIS registration for ESRI, MapInfo and Autodesk products – Directly integrate with your preferred GIS or combinations of GIS
```

Answer (score 0):

Ferrer, assuming you mean an [OS MasterMap address layer in the UK](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/address-layer-2/index.html), the format is stated as [GML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) or [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

In QGIS **add a vector layer** and choose a GML filter. This will add the layer to a new project in QGIS. CSV format can be added the same way (right above highlighted GML in screen snap).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@dakcarto is right you can directly open it qgis. beside this you can also do this with dragging *.gml file and drop in layers.

you can read some information about gml structure in OS MasterMap [here](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-mastermap/gml-explained.html).

> OS MasterMap is supplied in GML 2.1.2
>
> OpenGIS GML 2.1.2 implementation specification
>
> GML 2.1.2 was ratified by the OGC in September 2002 to bring it in
>   line with the W3C XML schema specification of May 2001.

i hope it helps you...